# md-tab label does not show completely in mobile view

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I'm using a md-tab-group to represent a bunch of tabs as follows:

```
<md-tab-group md-stretch-tabs>
    <md-tab label="ALL">
        ...
    </md-tab>
    <md-tab label="MAPS">
        ...
    </md-tab>
    <md-tab label="NEWS & EVENTS">
        ...
    </md-tab>
    <md-tab label="STAFF">
        ...
    </md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
```

The labels appear fine on the browser on my desktop, but as soon as I switch to mobile view, the "NEWS & EVENTS" tab label gets cut off. All I can see (depending on the screen size) is "NEWS &" and the rest of it is cut off. Even if I click on the tab, the full label is not displayed.

Is there any way for the entire label to be displayed?

Comment: can you make a plunker?  Tabs on mobile are often not ideal for this exact reason. In the tabs component i wrote i just made the labels start to stack on top of each other rather than shrink and cut the text off.  Many sites switch to small icons instead of text labels so they will fit.

Comment: I'm fairly new to Angular. How do I go about creating a plunker? Also, can you provide an example of how the labels are stacked on top of each other?

Comment: So here for example - http://imgur.com/a/j7Ey7

Comment: I am no plunker expert myself, but plunker is just a site where you can create a miniature running environment to emulate your issue. and other people can see it and change the code to see if their changes are successful in fixing your problem. Its hard to diagnose your problem without being able to look at the code, so plunker lets people do that.

Comment: Hi, I have created a plunker here: https://plnkr.co/edit/bYEnCqvO2ivRi8oFOymS

Comment: @user141834 any updated on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are using `md-stretch-tabs` attribute in your `md-tab-group`.

`md-stretch-tabs` will stretch your tabs group header bar and give an equal width to all the tab labels. Remove that property and you'll get it working as you want.

Update [plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/1joWlcAQneaMVtyMWo2I?p=info).

Comment: This doesn't really seem to be a complete solution... many mobile screens are between 320 px and 540 px in width, and this would still cut the labels off at those sizes.

Comment: This is the complete solution as far as tabs are concerned. On smaller screens, tabs header provides back and next arrows automatically. Whether the content gets cut, depends on the user design, but this solution will not allow tab labels to cut off. Please see the plunker demo I provided.

Comment: Yes i am not saying you're wrong. I did look at the Plunker. I am just saying it sounded like OP was wanting a solution where they wouldn't be cut off at all. Which is why my original comment was suggesting he may be out of luck with tabs on mobile. many people have stopped using them on mobile

Comment: your answer is still helpful though, which is why i upvoted

Comment: @diopside as I understood, the OP is only concerned about the tab label getting cut off. Thanks for the upvote though :)

Comment: Thank you for that, removing the md-stretch-tabs property still doesn't do what I'm after but I think that's due to the screen sizes as @diopside has said. I will still accept your answer.